# What does "said deuces" mean?

Tags: american-english, slang

What does "said deuces" mean?

From context in places I encountered the idiom - I can guess it means *to take one's leave*, *to depart*, or to *say goodbye*, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You provided no context -- none at all!

Comment: He said 'Deuces!' and left at the double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context too long for comment: Loose History.

Post WW2: the index and middle finger in an upright position forms a "V" shape and was used as a symbol for "victory".

In the 1970's: the same "V" shape was used as a representation to indicate peace (based on the peace symbol).

Decades later the same two finger "V" shape was slightly rotated and used to indicate "peace", or in particular, "peace out" (indicating that a person is leaving the current location or group).

In more recent years (past decade or more) the same two finger sideways "V" shape is nearly a 90 degree rotation of the victory/peace position and now is commonly spoken and shown at the same time. Deuces (two in Spanish) is spoken while showing the two finger sideways "V" and indicates peace out, leaving, [see you] later, bye, until next time, ....

As a side note: An upside-down V "/\" usually symbolizes legs and often used in a motion to indicate "walking" or "walking away".

Comment: BTW, there's this character: ∧

Answer (score 2):

***[Deuces!](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/6t3ztui)*** excl.
(Pron. of Span. adios!)

> (US campus) goodbye!
>
> 2012  [US] -  C. Eble UNC-CH Campus Sl. 2011 3: DEUCES — goodby: *‘I have to go to class. Deuces!’.*

(GDoS)